# Symfony 3.4.3 does not work with Codeception

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

I wanted to add codeception (^2.3) to my symfony 3.4.3 project.
I followed the the steps on the "Getting started" guide but as soon as I try to run `codecept run` I am presented with the following error message:

```
==== Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception ====

Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.7
Powered by PHPUnit 6.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder::isCompiled() in ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:981
Stack trace:
#0 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(132): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->setDefinition('service_contain...', Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition))
#1 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(807): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->__construct()
#2 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(759): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->getContainerBuilder()
#3 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Ker in ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 981

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder::isCompiled() in ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:981
Stack trace:
#0 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(132): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->setDefinition('service_contain...', Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition))
#1 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(807): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->__construct()
#2 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(759): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->getContainerBuilder()
#3 ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Ker in ~/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 981
```

I already tried clearing the caches for all environments. Anything else I could try?

Comment: You got codeception with all dependencies installed to vendor directory, but you are running phar file. Delete phar file, use vendor/bin/codecept directly instead.

Comment: `php vendor/bin/codecept run` produces the exact same error:
    Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.7 Powered by PHPUnit 6.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method...

Comment: Similar issues usually happens when different versions of classes are loaded from different sources. vendor vs phar or global install were popular causes, but "Redirecting" solved them.

Comment: The code in your error is calling method defined in its parent class. It could only missing if Container.php was loaded from Symfony 3.2 or older. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.4.3/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L981

Comment: My advice is to add var_dump(get_included_files()); die; before that line and check if DependencyInjection/Container.php is loaded from unexpected location.

Comment: @Naktibalda is does not seem to be loaded at all. Only line containing "Container" is the ContainerBuilder. symfony/symfony is installed as v3.4.3 on composer install, but the isCompiled() method is missing anyways. Any more Ideas?